# ListView is not getting fill_parent height

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am working on a listView adapter but my adapter is not getting fill parent height.

The codes are given below
Content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text=" Date : " />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Client " />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Id " />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Amount " />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Due " />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and main_activity file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    com.zerothtech.khudrotathyav1.Helper Helper = new com.zerothtech.khudrotathyav1.Helper();
    private ArrayList<HashMap> list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //---ListView----
        ListView lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        populateList();
        listviewAdapter adapter = new listviewAdapter(this, list);
        lview.setAdapter(adapter);
        //---ListView----
    }
}
```

populateList() is a function to populate my list.

After populating my Array with some dummy data, I am adding to to my listview using an adapter. However, all I can see is one row of data at a time. I can scroll in between that one row of data.

Thank you.

Comment: No scrollview needed for listview. remove it

Comment: There is not need to put `ListView` inside `ScrollView`. `ListView` is Scrolleble content itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Scrollview in Parent of listview in layout file to set full height of listview

**Note** : Never put Listview inside scrollview

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's my pleasuse. pl accept my answer so it's help to other

Answer (score 0):

I have check your layout. if you use list view then not use in scroll view.
I have correct your layout.

try this..

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:text=" Date : "
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:text=" Client "
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:text=" Id "
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:text=" Amount "
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:text=" Due "
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            />
    </LinearLayout>
```